# Git pull upstream branch not working

Tags: git, smartgit

I already have an upstream, local, and origin remotes configured and both git and SmartGit have downloaded updates from upstream previously, however I am new to git and still often find it confusing. My origin is a fork of another developers github repo, and my local is a copy.

I know there have been some updates to the upstream branch on github both today and yesterday, but I couldn't seem to download these via SmartGit. However the following worked with git in cmd:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout 1.0.8
git pull upstream 1.0.8
```

`checkout 1.0.8` returned "already on 1.0.8"
`pull upstream 1.0.8` reported that it had updated 5 files from a 30th July update, but it didn't show any of the updates from yesterday or today; However when I checked the local files the more recent updates had been downloaded.

My questions are:
1) Shouldn't a git pull report on either all files updated or at least the total number of files updated?
2) How can I get SmartGit to do the same when only the Fetch button is enabled and the Pull button is disabled (the upstream is configured).

Any ideas please?

UPDATE: This is the Branches right mouse click menu:
[image: Branches right mouse click menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SmartGit, select your *upstream* remote in the **Branches** view, right-click and invoke **Pull**. Confirm the dialog with **Fetch**.

Now SmartGit will update the *remote* branches of your *upstream* remote. As your *local* branches will most likely not be tracking the *upstream* *remote* branches, but your *origin* *remote* branches, a **Pull** won't work here (that's the same for Git command line). Instead, you should invoke **Merge** (or **Rebase**) and select the *upstream* branch you want to update from.

Comment: There's no **Pull** option in the right-click menu but there is a **Merge** option which you mention in your second paragraph. I don't want to update the remote branches of my upstream remote, indeed I don't have permission, I want to update my local copy.

If I select **Merge** I then get the options: Fast-Forward, Create Merge-Commit, or Merge to working tree.

Comment: When right-clicking your remote in the Branches view, there should be a **Pull** option. By updating the *remote branch* of your *upstream* remote, I meant that your local .git/refs/remotes/upstream/branch will be updated. This won't affect the remote repository on the server. Selecting either **Merge** option should be fine.

Comment: I see now there's a pull option when right clicking in the Branches box when right clicking on the repository name rather than on the branch name.